# Is it possible to receive keyword-level Google Display Network ad cost via the API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I've skimmed through the [Keywords Performance Report of the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/keywords-performance-report), and couldn't understand whether it would be possible for me to use this report to determine daily keyword costs.

What I want is basically to be able to look for keyword to an API request result and get the cost associated with it. Is such a thing possible? Am I looking in the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it's not possible to do so, since all costs on all Display Network items are listed with a special ID (3000000) in costs, meant to capture all GDN displays.